# Can't install TFS (Team Foundation Server) 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I've just applied Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and while attempting to apply TFS2010 SP1 (TFS2010SP1-KB2182621.exe), I got the following error message:

"KB2182621 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer."

I have Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010 installed on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Download Microsoft® Visual Studio Team Foundation Server® 2010, Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20506) page:

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2
>   (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008
>   R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2

Windows XP is not supported.